# PHP multidimensional array element removal with unset

Tags: php, arrays

Have this multidimensional array. How can I remove this element?

```
 [1]=>
    array(0) {
    }
```

Tried unset(), array_pop() but both do not work.

Example with unset():

```
echo "before\n";
var_dump($body['body'][0][1]);
unset($body['body'][0][1][1]);
echo "after\n";
var_dump($body['body'][0][1]);

before
array(4) {
  ["token_name"]=>
  string(7) "C_BLOCK"
  ["token_group"]=>
  string(7) "C_BLOCK"
  ["group"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["body"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["token_name"]=>
        string(12) "C_CASE_BLOCK"
        ["token_group"]=>
        string(12) "C_CASE_BLOCK"
        ["group"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(6) {
            ["token_name_org"]=>
            string(9) "T_LNUMBER"
            ["token"]=>
            int(317)
            ["value"]=>
            string(2) "10"
            ["line"]=>
            int(4)
            ["token_group"]=>
            string(9) "VARIABLES"
            ["token_name"]=>
            string(8) "C_NUMBER"
          }
        }
        ["body"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            array(6) {
              ["token_name_org"]=>
              string(6) "T_ECHO"
              ["token"]=>
              int(328)
              ["value"]=>
              string(4) "echo"
              ["line"]=>
              int(5)
              ["token_group"]=>
              string(9) "FUNCTIONS"
              ["token_name"]=>
              string(6) "C_ECHO"
            }
            [1]=>
            array(6) {
              ["token_name_org"]=>
              string(26) "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"
              ["token"]=>
              int(323)
              ["value"]=>
              string(4) "test"
              ["line"]=>
              int(5)
              ["token_group"]=>
              string(7) "STRINGS"
              ["token_name"]=>
              string(8) "C_STRING"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
after
array(4) {
  ["token_name"]=>
  string(7) "C_BLOCK"
  ["token_group"]=>
  string(7) "C_BLOCK"
  ["group"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["body"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["token_name"]=>
        string(12) "C_CASE_BLOCK"
        ["token_group"]=>
        string(12) "C_CASE_BLOCK"
        ["group"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(6) {
            ["token_name_org"]=>
            string(9) "T_LNUMBER"
            ["token"]=>
            int(317)
            ["value"]=>
            string(2) "10"
            ["line"]=>
            int(4)
            ["token_group"]=>
            string(9) "VARIABLES"
            ["token_name"]=>
            string(8) "C_NUMBER"
          }
        }
        ["body"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            array(6) {
              ["token_name_org"]=>
              string(6) "T_ECHO"
              ["token"]=>
              int(328)
              ["value"]=>
              string(4) "echo"
              ["line"]=>
              int(5)
              ["token_group"]=>
              string(9) "FUNCTIONS"
              ["token_name"]=>
              string(6) "C_ECHO"
            }
            [1]=>
            array(6) {
              ["token_name_org"]=>
              string(26) "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"
              ["token"]=>
              int(323)
              ["value"]=>
              string(4) "test"
              ["line"]=>
              int(5)
              ["token_group"]=>
              string(7) "STRINGS"
              ["token_name"]=>
              string(8) "C_STRING"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Why it is shown anyway, doesn't array(0) means an array with zero elements? Why it is there than?

```
   [1]=>
        array(0) {
        }
```

Comment: and with `unset($body['body'][0][1]['body'][1]);` ?

Comment: as i can see you were unseting that key which is not exist try @AlessandroMinoccheri answer

Comment: THANK YOU!!! @CasimiretHippolyte WORKS!!!! Was looking at indexing, but could not figure it out. Your solution works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this please:

```
unset($body['body'][1]);
```

**UPDATE**

try this:

```
unset($body['body'][0][1]['body'][1]);
```

You need to unset the right index

Comment: Take care that the dump doesn't display `$body` but `$body['body'][0][1]`.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this out:

```
$clear = array();
foreach($your_array_variable as $key=>$val){
    $val = '';
    $clear [$key] = $val;
}
```

print_r($clear);
reference: [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971725/unset-entire-array)

OR

```
foreach (my_array_keys($array, 'apple') as $key) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

OR

```
// destroy a single variable
unset($foo);

// destroy a single element of an array
unset($bar['body']);

// destroy more than one variable
unset($foo1, $foo2, $foo3);
```